# How did this site guessed my chrome browser history?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, browser, favicon

How did https://favicon-leak.site guessed my chrome browser history? I tried go to incognito and get same results. As I understand it, this is done with javascript. But which browser api gives me access to browser history?

Is this normal behavior or this is a real security vulnerability?

Comment: Did you follow the ["How it works?"](https://webw.medium.com/your-chrome-history-leaks-via-favicon-check-now-764b4d4eb33b) link on the page you linked? And yes, [it's a security vulnerability](https://www.google.com/search?q=ndss21%20favicon).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article on Medium.com](https://webw.medium.com/your-chrome-history-leaks-via-favicon-check-now-764b4d4eb33b) explaining this.

The author ***Max Judkin*** says the following:

> *Chrome has two types of resource caches: disk and memory. As many have guessed, disk cache is a permanent storage for resources (images, css, js, etc.), but with its own read delay (1+ ms). Memory cache is used for temporary storage of frequently used resources and reading is performed without delays (0 ms). Thus, by placing a resource in the memory cache, browser reduces number of reads from the disk and increases performance.*
>
> *When we first load a picture via `<img>`, it will either be loaded via src or taken from the disk cache. In both cases, this picture is placed in the memory cache (most often). Let’s look at the following javascript code:*
>
> ```js
> var img = new Image();
> img.src = some_image_url;
> if (img.complete && img.height + img.width > 0) {
>
> // This condition is TRUE only when the picture has been successfully read from the memory cache
> }
> ```
>
> *From this fact, we can draw the following conclusion: if you load `<img>` twice, then the second time the picture should be loaded from the memory cache.*